# Side menu transition speed

Tags: codenameone

How can we increase the speed of transition between opening or closing of side menu and also change the duration or speed of form transition (going from one form to another?

Answer (score 0):

There is a theme constant `sideMenuAnimSpeedInt` which defaults to 300ms.

Another constant is available for forms `transitionSpeedInt` which defaults to 220ms at this time.